# excute query with large data in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a large file to insert into phpmyadmin, 
I wrote a query that reads from file and inserts into db, 
it works fine , but inserts only about 65 rows then stops .

Comment: Any output from logs? apache, or php logs?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use?

Comment: phpmyadmin is dreadfully slow, you'll probably find its PHP timing out, checkout adminer, this is a far better sql admin tool for php.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a case of execution time out for php.
Can you have a try setting up the max_execution_time through set_time_limit  function.

When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Warning:
This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php